# How to sort an array by datetime in multiple named attributes

Tags: ruby

```
Album.album_release_date
Ep.ep_release_date
Song.song_release_date
```

Is there an easy way to do order this array by the differently named datetime attributes?

```
[album1, album2, album3, ep1, ep2, song1, song2, song3].order_by(the three differently named datetime attributes above, newest to oldest)
```

Comment: Might be easier if I had called them all 'release_date'.

Comment: Yes, just `release_date` would have allowed for `[album1, album2, album3, ep1, ep2, song1, song2, song3].sort_by(&:release_date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick.

```
release_date_methods = {
  Album => :album_release_date,
  Ep => :ep_release_date,
  Song => :song_release_date,
}
release_date_methods.default = :release_date

releasables.sort_by { |releasable| releasable.then(&release_date_methods[releasable.class]) }
```

I first create a hash containing different methods for different classes. Then fetch the method using the releasable class and pass it as block to [`releasable.then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-then).

However it would be better to change the method names if possible. If every element in the array responds to `:release_date` they conform to the same interface. This would allow you to simply use:

```
releasables.sort_by(&:release_date)
```

Comment: Worked!   ... worked backwards (oldest to newest), but I put a .reverse on it afterwards.  1) I don't know what to_proc does, 2) I don't know what .call does.   I shall investigate at a later time, thank you.

Comment: @daveasdf I've updated the answer and removed all `to_proc` calls. They let the answer look more complicated then it actually is. Instead I've opted to use [`then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-then) (introduced in Ruby 2.6.0). This hopefully makes the answer better understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and readable sorting method:

```rb
def my_sort(items)
  class_and_attr_map = {
    'Album' => :album_release_date,
    'Ep' => :ep_release_date,
    'Song' => :song_release_date
  }
  items.sort_by do |item|
    sorted_attr_name = class_and_attr_map[item.class.name]
    item.public_send sorted_attr_name
  end
end
```

The point is using `Hash` to remember the map between class name and method name. To invoke method with a name, we use `public_send`.

Comment: Thank you.   ... This looks like something you'd put in a model?   How would I invoke this on an array in my controller?

Comment: If this is used in only one controller, I'd put it into the controller and make it private. Otherwise, I'd create a new class only for this method.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some instances.

```
require 'date'
```

```
def random_date
  [*Date.new(2020,1,1)..Date.new(2020,1,29)].sample
end
```

```
class Album
  attr_reader :album_release_date
  def initialize; @album_release_date = random_date; end
end

class Ep
  attr_reader :ep_release_date
  def initialize; @ep_release_date = random_date; end
end

class Song
  attr_reader :song_release_date
  def initialize; @song_release_date = random_date; end
end
```

```
arr = [Album.new, Album.new, Album.new, Ep.new, Ep.new,
       Song.new, Song.new, Song.new]
  #=> [
  #    #<Album:...@album_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-15...>,
  #    #<Album:...@album_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-06...>, 
  #    #<Album:...@album_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-22...>,
  #    #<Ep:...@ep_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-13...>,
  #    #<Ep:...@ep_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-17...>,
  #    #<Song:...@song_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-11...>,
  #    #<Song:...@song_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-17...>,
  #    #<Song:...@song_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-29...>
  #   ]
```

We may sort these by date as follows:

```
arr.sort_by do |inst|
  case inst
  when Album
    inst.album_release_date
  when Ep
    inst.ep_release_date
  when Song
    inst.song_release_date
  else
    # <raise exception>
  end
end
  #=> [
  #    #<Album:...@album_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-06...>, 
  #    #<Song:...@song_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-11...>,
  #    #<Ep:...@ep_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-13...>,
  #    #<Album:...@album_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-15...>,
  #    #<Ep:...@ep_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-17...>,
  #    #<Song:...@song_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-17...>,
  #    #<Album:...@album_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-22...>,
  #    #<Song:...@song_release_date=#<Date: 2020-01-29...>
  #   ]
```

Comment: While that'll work, it seems like it would have been much easier calling it `release_date` everywhere.

Comment: @theTinMan, I agree, if that's an option. For all we know changing the names of those instance variables would have such far-reaching implications that it would be impractical to do so.